# Open MPI error to define MPI_Datatype in header file

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I need to define a (Open MPI) MPI_Datatype in a header file so that all other files that include it can find it.

I also try to use extern to do decleration in .h file and then define them in .cpp file.

But, I always get error:

undefined reference

It is not allowed in Open MPI ?

Why ?

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: More info needed. What exactly is your code, how do you compile, and which line gives the undefined reference error?

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't provide all the information.

But here's some quick point when working with MPI .

Define in your header file :

1. the MPI Message IDs in an enum. This message ID can reflect your component name, message type with some bit shifting operation.
2. The Desination Node types (whether broadcast, multicast, or specific NodeIdentifier) in an enum .
3. registration mechanism to register the call back function pointers against the MPI Message IDs . Thus when a given node receives a perticular type of message it will execute this call back function in the context of the MPI receiver thread.

If you have any specific questions, just edit your question post.